# UICollectionView Animation on cell deletion

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and inside each cell, there is a delete button to remove the cell. I wish to animate the deletion process. I was looking into some articles and I found this. Batch update can make the animations. This is the code I am using. indexPath is the Index Path of the cell I wish to delete.

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
collectionViewLove?.performBatchUpdates({() -> Void in self.collectionViewLove?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])}, completion: nil)
```

However, every time I get this error.

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (9) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Why is this happening?

Comment: you have to delete that object from the array from which you are filling the data

Comment: so add the answer and close this

Comment: Closing means accepting the answer you added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to delete the respective UICollectionView data source array object.